# Generate another blueprint from an Ember CLI blueprint

Tags: ember.js, code-generation, ember-cli

I've created a custom blueprint based on the docs at [ember-cli](https://ember-cli.com/extending/) and I want to run a *different* blueprint (essentially `ember g something-else ...`) from inside my first blueprint. How can I do this?

Specific use-case: I've overrode Ember CLI's default Component blueprint, and I want to generate a matching CSS partial (in `app/styles/components/`) for every generated Component, inside my new Component blueprint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your generator (probably `app/blueprints/blueprint-name/index.js`):

```
var Blueprint = require('ember-cli/lib/models/blueprint');

module.exports = {

  ...

  afterInstall: function(options) {
    var otherBlueprint = Blueprint.lookup('other-blueprint-name', {
      paths: [path.resolve(__dirname, '..')]
    });

    return otherBlueprint.install(options);
  },
};
```

Thanks to [nullnullnull](http://discuss.emberjs.com/users/nullnullnull/) for pointing out this approach at [calling-ember-g-component-within-a-blueprints-index-js](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/calling-ember-g-component-within-a-blueprints-index-js/8739).

Comment: have you been able to get this to work since the ember and ember-data blueprints were moved out of Ember-CLI and into their respective repos?

I've tried importing the [ember-cli-legacy-blueprints](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-legacy-blueprints) addon but the only thing it exports is the blueprint name.

Comment: @ultimatemonty are you still importing Ember Data via Bower? Haven't tried that config. This works for me on Ember CLI 2.7.0 (so the blueprints have been moved out).